# Regex to strip trailing 0 but keep the value to a specific length

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to strip values of trailing zeroes but also need to keep the final length of the values to 4.

```
+--------+
|codes   |
+--------+
|  541100|
|  54100 |
|  05810 |
|  581200|
|  58140 |
|  54110 |
|  48140 |
|  481400|
|  723000 |
|  52000 |
+--------+
```

the below line is trimming all the trailing zeroes , how do i make sure that it maintains a length of 4.

```
df.withColumn("strip_codes", regexp_replace(col("codes"), "^([0]+(?!$))|0*$", ""))
```

also, I want to ignore the value `05810` to match the regex for trailing zeroes 
o/p DF

```
+--------+
|strip_codes   |
+--------
|  5411|
|  5410|
|  05810|
|  5812|
|  5814|
|  5411|
|  4814|
|  4814|
|  7230|
|  5200|
+--------+
```

what changes do i need to make in the existing regex.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to remove 05810? Or change it to 5810? Or 0581?

Comment: for now i just want to ignore this value and don't want any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will nullify codes of length > 6, leave codes that match a special list unchanged; and for the rest, the `regex` pattern will remove all leading zeros, keep 4 of the following digits, and trim any remaining trailing zeros:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  "541100", "54110", "05810", "581200", "58140", 
  "54110", "48140", "481400", "723000", "52000",
  "0742", "0763", "001234", "123", "1234560"
).toDF("codes")

val specialList = Array("0742", "0763", "0780")

df.withColumn("strip_code", when(length($"codes") > 6, null).otherwise(
  when($"codes".isin(specialList: _*), $"codes").otherwise(
    regexp_replace($"codes", "^[0]*(\\d{4}.*?)[0]*$", "$1"))
  )
).show
// +-------+----------+
// |  codes|strip_code|
// +-------+----------+
// | 541100|      5411|
// |  54110|      5411|
// |  05810|      5810|
// | 581200|      5812|
// |  58140|      5814|
// |  54110|      5411|
// |  48140|      4814|
// | 481400|      4814|
// | 723000|      7230|
// |  52000|      5200|
// |   0742|      0742|
// |   0763|      0763|
// | 001234|      1234|
// |    123|       123|
// |1234560|      null|
// +-------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regex.how did you skipped 05810

Comment: The regex simply keeps all leading zeros plus the next 4 digits, thus leaving "05810" unchanged; whereas for numbers without leading zeros, the leading 4 digits will be kept.

Comment: That means if the code is 005810, it will give 00581 and remove the last 0

Comment: No, it'll leave "005810" as is, since the regex keeps ALL leading zeros as well as the next 4 digits.

Comment: Oh. thanks a lot. I think this will work out. let me try it on a huge data, if there are any exceptions I will update it

Comment: And suppose i want to ignore any other code that does not begin with 0, say 99990 and keep as it is without trimming

Comment: Do you have clear criteria of codes that need to be left as is?  Is there a list of such codes?  Or a specific pattern?

Comment: yes, currently i have three codes that needs to be left out if there are multiple leading 0's. 0742, 0763, 0780.
suppose if the codes are `00742, 07630, 00780` then the result will be `0742,0763,0780`. apart from these three if any other code has a leading 0 that can also be scraped off, but limiting to 4 digits

Comment: and is it also possible that if the code is more than 6 digit to make it null instead of extracting the first 4 digits

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a baseline solution (which you can further refine) for your expanded requirement.

Comment: Thanks @LeoC.. one more that i am trying to do is if there are codes starting with 0 that are not in the specialList, then i want to trim all leading 0's and pick the first 4 digit.

Comment: how to trim the leading 0 and take 4 digits? 
`+-------+
|   mcc1|
+-------+
| 541100|
|  54110|
|  05810|
| 581200|
|  58140|
|  54110|
|  48140|
| 481400|
|  72300|
|   5200|
|   0742|
|   0763|
|  01234|
|    123|
|1234560|
+-------+`

Comment: You'll just need to exclude the leading zeros from the regex group (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
df.show()

+------+
| value|
+------+
|541100|
| 54100|
| 05810|
|581200|
| 58140|
| 54110|
| 48140|
|481400|
|723000|
| 52000|
+------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("cleanedValue",when(substring('value,1,1).rlike("0"),'value)
                            .otherwise(substring('value,1,4)))
                            .show() 

+------+------------+
| value|cleanedValue|
+------+------------+
|541100|        5411|
| 54100|        5410|
| 05810|       05810|
|581200|        5812|
| 58140|        5814|
| 54110|        5411|
| 48140|        4814|
|481400|        4814|
|723000|        7230|
| 52000|        5200|
+------+------------+
```

Comment: if the code has a alphanumeric value say `1234AZSHND`, then the value should return null instead of 1234. how can i change that in your code?